# Отсутствует вывод на экран

Tags: php

Начал проходить уроки по PHP и столкнулся c проблемой. При добавлении в базу данных или при пустой `input`-те ничего не выводится на экран.

1. Главный файл:

   ```
   <?php session_start();?>
   <?php require_once("libs.php");?>
   <?php require_once("conec.php");?>
   <?php
   if($_POST['submit']){
       $name =trim(mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['name']));
       $phone =trim(mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['phone']));
       $age =trim((int)$_POST['age']);
       $error = '';
       if(empty($name)) $error .= "<p>Не заполнено Имя</p>";
       if(empty($phone)) $error .= "<p>Не заполнено Телефон</p>";
       if(empty($age)) $error .= "<p>Не заполнено Возраст</p>";
       if(empty($error)) {
          if (newContact($name, $phone, $age)){
              $_SESSION['res'] = '<p>ДОБАВЛЕННО</p>';
              header("Location: new.php");
              exit;
          }else{
              $_SESSION['res'] = '<p>ОШИБКА</p>';
              header("Location: new.php");
              exit;
          }
       }else{
           $_SESSION['res'] = $error;
           header("Location: new.php");
           exit;
       }
   }
   ?>
   <?php require_once("menu.php");?>
   <form action="" method="post">
       <p>Имя*: <input type="text"  name"name"></p>
       <p>Телефон: <input type="text"  name"phone"></p>
       <p>Возраст: <input type="text"  name"age"></p>
       <p><input type="submit" value="Добавить"></p>
   </form>
   <?= $_SESSION['res'];
       session_unset();
       session_destroy();
   ?>
   ```
2. Файл `libs.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   // показ абонентов
   function showAll() {
       $query = "select * from test";
       $res = mysql_query($query);
       $data = array();
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       $data[] = $row;
       }
       return $data;
   }
   //..Добавление абонента
   function newContact($name, $phone, $age) {
       $query = "insert into test (name, phone, age) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', $age)";
      $res = mysql_query($query);
      if( mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. Файл `conec.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   // показ абонентов
   function showAll() {
       $query = "select * from test";
       $res = mysql_query($query);
       $data = array();
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
           $data[] = $row;
       }
       return $data;
   }
   //..Добавление абонента
   function newContact($name, $phone, $age) {
       $query = "insert into test (name, phone, age) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', $age)";
      $res = mysql_query($query);
      if( mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: а какую версию php вы используете ?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... }`*

Comment: Вообще лучше использовать  `mysqli`. Это так, уходя от проблемы.

Comment: может вывод ошибок включить

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется падает скрипт. И предположительно на

```
$name =trim(mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['name']));
```

Потому что передается "", совсем пустая с значением len=0 и для нее делается trim.

Вообщем, я бы везде натыкал отладку и проследил где обрывается скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

1. Это конечно `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {/* other code */}`
2. Не уверен, что можно short_tags так использовать. Я бы написал классически:

> ```
> <?php 
>     echo $_SESSION['res'];
>     session_unset();
>     session_destroy();
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Спасибо всем я нашёл ошибку.

в `input type:submit` нет `name:submit`.

скрипт ссылается в никуда.

Comment: выкинь свои уроки, у тебя устаревший  и очень плохой учебник

Comment: подскажи ПЛИЗ другие уроки

Comment: google://php mysqli ооп. ооп выдаст учебники на русском, mysqli убережет от совсем устаревших учебников

Comment: Хотел спросить с чего вы взяли что мои уроки старые. и где найти новые?

Comment: старые - потому, что mysql_ расширение очень давно устарело и в php 7 уже удалено, новые найти указывая год (2015, 2016) и/или версию php -> php 7, например